# Is there a universal way to calculate model likelihoods for an arbitrary distribution?

Tags: model-selection, likelihood, goodness-of-fit, aic, bic

I have no background in statistics but have been tasked to use AIC and BIC to select a model for some observed experimental data. The population data cannot be assumed to obey any particular distribution. I have fitted several models to the data and need to compute likelihoods to use for AIC and BIC.

Given some data that come from a population with an unknown probability distribution and a model that describes the data, is there a universal way of computing the likelihood of the model, i.e, the probability that the distribution precisely described by the model would yield the observed data through random sampling? Is there a fast way to calculate AIC and BIC from these data alone?

Comment: Why are you being tasked with doing a complex statistical analysis despite having no background in statistics?

Comment: I'm an undergrad working in a research lab; I'm a math major so sometimes my supervisor will hand me these kinds of tasks for me to learn and implement on my own.

Comment: That presents a bit of a problem, because your use of AIC and BIC for model selection, depending on what you're doing, can invalidate your analysis. This is related to, if not the same as, [criticisms of stepwise regression](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/). If you will be doing an invalid analysis with the model, does it matter how you calculate the likelihood to get the AIC (or BIC) to determine the best model with which you are doing the invalid analysis? You might want to post a new question that gets into what you're doing with your modeling.